# Removing duplicates based on matching column values with boolean indexing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean-logic

After merging two DF's I have the following dataset:

| DB_ID | x_val | y_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x01 | 405 | 407 |
| x01 | 405 | 405 |
| x02 | 308 | 306 |
| x02 | 308 | 308 |
| x03 | 658 | 658 |
| x03 | 658 | 660 |
| x04 | None | 658 |
| x04 | None | 660 |
| x05 | 658 | 660 |
| x06 | 660 | 660 |

The y table contains multiple values for the left join variable (not included in table), resulting in multiple rows per unique DB_ID (string variable, not in df index).

The issue is that only one row is correct, where x_val and y_val match. I tried removing the duplicates with the following code:
`df= df[~df['DB_ID'].duplicated() | combined['x_val'] != combined['y_val']]`

This however doesn't work. I am looking for a solution to achieve the following result:

| DB_ID | x_val | y_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x01 | 405 | 405 |
| x02 | 308 | 308 |
| x03 | 658 | 658 |
| x04 | None | 658 |
| x05 | 658 | 660 |
| x06 | 660 | 660 |

Comment: Can you add some non duplicated rows by `DB_ID` and expected ouput? E.G `x04  100  100`

Comment: also whats happens if add `x01  405  405`, so 2 duplicated rows per `x01` ?

Comment: and whats happens if add `x05  200  300` ?

Comment: @jezrael, done! It is a very tricky table, the x_val and y_val are used to check whether a correct joining variable was used. x_val and y_val are an object id variable that should match between both tables. If they don't match, I describe so in another column with a specific value. So the values shouldn't be dropped. x04 is especially tricky since no object ID is available for X but two entries are returned based on the joining value. In this case, it doesn't matter which row is kept. But I can't allow for any DB_ID duplicates. Keeping matching x_val & y_val has the strongest preference.

Comment: @jezrael adding the variables as a criteria for the merge doesn't work in my case because the variable is sometimes missing for the x table, but based on the joining variable two variables may be returned even for x04 where x_val = None or NaN

Comment: Solution was changed, can you test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is compare both column for not equal, then sorting and reove duplicates by `DB_ID`:

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['x_val'].ne(df['y_val']))
        .sort_values(['DB_ID','new'])
        .drop_duplicates('DB_ID')
        .drop('new', axis=1))
print (df)
  DB_ID x_val y_val
1   x01   405   405
3   x02   308   308
4   x03   658   658
6   x04  None   658
8   x05   658   660
9   x06   660   660
```

If need equal `NaN`s or `None`s use:

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['x_val'].fillna('same').ne(df['y_val'].fillna('same')))
        .sort_values(['DB_ID','new'])
        .drop_duplicates('DB_ID')
        .drop('new', axis=1))
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can simply use:

```
df = df[df['x_val'] == df['y_val']]
print(df)

# Output
  DB_ID  x_val  y_val
1   x01    405    405
3   x02    308    308
4   x03    658    658
```

I think you don't need `drop_duplicates` or `duplicated` but if you want to ensure there remains only one instance of each `DB_ID`, you can append `.drop_duplicates('DB_ID')`

```
df = df[df['x_val'] == df['y_val']].drop_duplicates('DB_ID')
print(df)

# Output
  DB_ID  x_val  y_val
1   x01    405    405
3   x02    308    308
4   x03    658    658
```